# JSON output null in Firefox/Opera, correct in Chrome

Tags: php, json, response

*Note: I'm not considering this is Drupal problem so I post it here on SO.*

We created a Drupal module that is supposed to return JSON. E.g. calling /foo/json returns the JSON. This is all fine in Chrome. However, Firefox just shows "null".

The contents of the JSON is simply a PHP array with some information that gets populated with a loop

```
$someArray = array();
foreach(....) {
   $someArray[] = array("foo" => "bar", ...);
}

echo json_encode($someArray);
```

So far, I know that

- it is not an encoding issue. If I only return a single element from `$someArray[0]["some_key"]`, Chrome shows `"USA"` with a `Content Length` of *5*, so I am sure that there is not a single non-ASCII character. However, Firefox shows `null` with a Content Length of *4*.
- doing a `wget` gives me the correct content with all the JSON. Since I trust wget more than the browser, I assume that it is not a Drupal/.htaccess issue.
- The JSON is well-formed according to jsonlint.com and since the PHP function does the conversion, I assume it is really well-formed.
- other stuff like permissions (everybody is allowed to acces the page) or encoding (sending UTF-8) doesn't change the result.
- This is not jQuery/cross-domain related since I just want to call the URL in the browser and want to see the JSON response.
- On another machine with the same (Drupal) set-up, the result is the same.
- I am able to return JSON from other directories that are not related to the Drupal setup. But since I just do a `json_encode`, I bypass every possible output by Drupal and since `wget` works I it's not related to Drupal IMO.

*updates according to comments*

- Content-type is `application/json` with proper encoding information. Changing it to text/html or something else doesn't change anything. Using both `header` as well as the Drupal function for setting headers.
- I am sure that the `null` repsonse is correct, since I inspected it with Firebug.
- `ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');` doesn't change anything since I already submit this information within the header.

Response header from Firefox with Firebug

```
Cache-Control   no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection          Keep-Alive
Content-Language    en
Content-Length  4
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Date            Mon, 03 Sep 2012 12:16:58 GMT
Etag            "1346674618"
Expires         Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive          timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified   Mon, 03 Sep 2012 12:16:58 +0000
Server          Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2
```

Request header

```
Accept          text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.3
Connection          keep-alive
Cookie          has_js=1; respimg_ratio=1; respimg=1000 //Drupal information
Host            vie.local
User-Agent          Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0
```

**TL;DR**
While Chrome shows correct (well-formed) JSON output, Firefox (and also tested in in Opera) only show `null` even for simplest string like `"USA"`.

Comment: Try setting the response header type application/json

Comment: What `Content-type` header are you setting in the PHP output?

Comment: And you didn't say so, but have you actually inspected the HTTP response in Firebug or the Firefox network console?

Comment: I have updated my question with your requests.

Comment: have you tried to set UTF-8 using ini_set() ??

Comment: can you give an example url so we can test for ourselves?

Comment: yes vlad is right,if you can provide the link it would be great to find the solution earlier

Comment: @VladBalmos I'm not sure, I need to ask my supervisor for this if we can give make some of the data public but since we tried it ourself on different machines in different places with the same results, it *should* not make a difference, I will come back with an answer to this.

Comment: @DrColossos can you post the whole http request and response (including headers and body) for firefox?

Comment: if it works in other browsers it's not a php related problem, but something on the client side

Comment: @VladBalmos Updated the question with request/response header. Should have added this information beforehand. And I agree that this is likely to be a client thing, but it's hard to pin it down with only a null on your screen :(

Comment: @DrColossos are you using ajax?

Comment: @DrColossos Set the Content-type to text/html and post back what it is ouputed. Maybe you are echoing some chars before or after the json data and firefox fails to see it as valid json response.

Comment: @DrColossos what happens when you try to json an empty array?

Comment: @VladBalmos Both browsers show the expected result `[]`. The moment something is contained within this array, it still works. It only fails when accessing the `$someArray` array from the example above that got populated within the loop.

Comment: Can you post the correct JSON response that you receive using Chrome / wget

Comment: Finally found the solution. Thanks to anyone who participated, especially Vlad Balmos. You got me to the right direction. I posted the answer seperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Firefox, somehow, was not sending the correct language to the server. I don't know if via cookies or within the headers. Since I used language aware filtering for the output, the output was never returned.

So disabling the language filter solved the problem. I have no idea why Firefox had issues with the language but this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As i said in my comment, there may be an issue with how you are sending back the json response to the browser

> it is not an encoding issue. If I only return a single element from $someArray[0]["some_key"], Chrome shows "USA" with a Content Length of 5, so I am sure that there is not a single non-ASCII character. However, Firefox shows null with a Content Length of 4.

null returns a Content Length of 4

USA returns Content Length of 5? Why? USA has only 3 chars

Check for white spacing before or after the response

Answer (score 0):

**Sending a json file into a header for XMLHttpRequest use**

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("path/well_formated.json");
```

using

```
header("header_name: $json_string"));
```

fails for FF and

```
header("header_name:". json_encode($json_string));
```

fails for all

**php HEREDOC solution**

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("path/well_formated.json");
$h= <<<H
header_name : $json
H;
header($h);
```

This will work well in Chrome,Opera,Firefox,IE